# What is "Program Files (x86)" actully used for

Tags: windows-7, installation, path

i was installing Sekien no Inganock ~What a Beautiful People~ Fullvoice Reborn onto my computer last night, since learning about Symbolic links i've created a Visual Novels Folder in Program Files, Visual Novels that i had previously installed in their default locations have a symbolic link in this folder and their organized properly (ie. all Lair Soft games go into one folder, all Type-Moon gaesm go in another, Type Moon games are broken into 2 groups, Fate and Tsukihime for the 2 different stories (Fate/stay Night, Fate/Hollow Ataxia/Tsukihime, Melty Blood))

Sekien no Inganock ~What a Beautiful People~ was originally installed into

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Liar/Sekien no Inganock

(i renamed the folder from the japanese text after the translation patch was applied) so it got a Symbolic Link in

> C:/Program Files/Visual Novels/Liar-Soft/~What a Beautiful~/Sekien no
>   Inganock ~What a Beautiful People~/Sekien no Inganock ~What a
>   Beautiful People~

i did the folder structure like that cause i was aware at the time of the translation of the REBORN edition and was going to get it aswell, i went to install it, natully the installer defaulted to Program Files (x86), i changed the path to my new one however after it was installed the folder didn't appear where i though it would and the icon was on the desktop (indicating that it had been installed)

using the icon to go to where it had been installed and i found that it had been installed into the path i specified yet the (x86) has been added, despite the fact that i didn't add that

after uninstalling and this time using browse to click on the folder (rather than type it out like i did) it did the same thing, rather than installing into Program Files like i specified it installed it into Program Files (x86), the rest of the path remain fine (so it clearly wasn't getting the default file path)

i have installed Bazooka Cafe and Cavas 2, Bazooka Cafe wanted to be installed into Program Files (x86) however i specified it into Program Files and it installed fine and works like a charm (apart from crash at the title menu cause by my friend's Censor Patch which she fixed up), Cavas 2 just wanted to be installed into the root directory of C, i changed the path to Program Files and it worked out fine

now the only thing i can think of is that Windows is forcing my Sekien no Inganock REBORN installer to always install into Program Files (x86) when i specify Program Files, so i am wondering, what is the exact purpose of the 2 Program Files cause i always though that it was for compatibility with older Installers that use %ProgramFiles% and 32-bit installer to separate from 64-bit programs and it was solely just to make thing look neater and that it wasn't an enforced thing

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Remove all information not directly connected to your question.  The purpose of this folder is also well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound one answer i saw said it's used to seperate 32 and 64-bit of the same application so you dont overwrite the program or require a 32bin or 64bin folder, this makes no sense, if the 32-bit version doesn't work on your 64-bit system, uninstall it and install the 64-bit version, if the 64-bit version doesn't work on your system for god know what reason, use the 32-bit, i see no reason why you would have the same program twice unless your a programmer in which case you wouldn't be lazy and let Windows install the program for you (you would specify the directories yourself)

Comment: @Ramhound also, as my question points out, Windows is forcing the (x86) to my path despite the fact that 1. i didn't put it there and 2. 2 other programs which are much older worked just fine when i put it in Program Files, as for removing information, no idea what i should remove, i added everything to avoid some idiot replying "just use the (x86) folder" or "just use the default install location", i want to know exactly why there are 2 Program Files folders and why Windows is trying to enforce me to install 1 program into one

Comment: your question contain so much irrelevant information I simply stopped reading it.  The 86 Program File folder is an invisible compatibility layer for 32-bit support. You will be unable to remove the folder and you should not fight the feature.  I will come back when the question is easier to read.  Yes the answer is to accept this functionality it exists to support 32-bit applications through WOW64.

Comment: You could have asked this question in 30 words or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question contains so much superfluous information, it's nearly impossible to read the whole thing without getting confused, but nevertheless, in 64-bit Windows systems, the (x86) designation for Program Files is a layer of compatibility support for 32-bit software (as [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/634474/what-is-program-files-x86-actully-used-for/634528#comment792067_634474) pointed out).

Because there is so much software that supports both 32-bit and 64-bit instruction sets (therefore creating installations in both folders), and software that only supports 32-bit (needing the (x86) folder), it would be both unwise and unnecessary to delete it.

If it really is a hassle for you, you could simply switch to a 32-bit version of Windows and you would then only have one instruction set to deal with (and therefore, one "Program Files" folder).

This feature is also extremely well-documented, and easily searchable.

Comment: "This feature is also extremely well-documented, and easily searchable." Amen.